# Rails 5.2.0 images.attach results in InvalidSignature error

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am upgrading to Rails 5.2.0 and attempting to use ActiveStorage to save images from a data feed.  In `development.rb` I have `config.active_storage.service = :local` and the model has `has_many_attached :images` and `storage.yml` has the default `:local` settings and the controller action has

```
def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:beds, :baths, :price, :parking, :description, :active, :prop_type, :latitude, :longitude, :address, :city, :city_id, :state, :state_id, :zip, :lo_name, :la_fname, :la_lname, :la_phone, :la_email, :mlsid, :cp, :st_number, :st_suffix, :baths_full, :baths_half, :status, :modtime, :st_name, :featured, :school_id, :picture_count, :parking_type, images: [])
    end
```

My code is getting hung up on this line

`listing.images.attach(pics)` with this error: `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature`

My code:

```
def perform
    require 'aws-sdk-s3'
    require 'rets'

    client = Rets::Client.new({
      login_url: LOGIN_URL,
      username: LOGIN,
      password: PASSWORD,
      version: VERSION
     })

    begin
      client.login
    rescue => e
      puts 'Error: ' + e.message
      exit!
    end

    p "Logged in"

    Listing.find_each do |listing|
      mlsid = listing.mlsid
      photos = client.objects '*', {
         resource: 'Property',
         object_type: 'Photo',
         resource_id: mlsid
       }
       p "about to attempt to attach #{photos.count} images to listing#{listing.id}"
      pics = []
      photos.each do |data|
        pics << data.body
      end
      listing.images.attach(pics)
      puts "#{photos.count} images attached to listing##{listing.id}"
    end
  end
```

And the full error after running with --trace:

```
tomb$ rake update:listing_images --trace
    ** Invoke update:listing_images (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    ** Execute update:listing_images
    Cookie#domain returns dot-less domain name now. Use Cookie#dot_domain if you need "." at the beginning.
    "Logged in"
    "about to attempt to attach 16 images to listing2873"
    rake aborted!
    ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature: ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:176:in `verify'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:43:in `find_signed'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/lib/active_storage/attached.rb:30:in `create_blob_from'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/lib/active_storage/attached/many.rb:26:in `block in attach'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/lib/active_storage/attached/many.rb:22:in `collect'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/lib/active_storage/attached/many.rb:22:in `attach'
    /Users/tomb/Projects/schoolsparrow/app/jobs/listing_image_job.rb:43:in `block in perform'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:70:in `each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:70:in `block in find_each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:136:in `block in find_in_batches'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:238:in `block in in_batches'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:222:in `loop'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:222:in `in_batches'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:135:in `find_in_batches'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:69:in `find_each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:11:in `find_each'
    /Users/tomb/Projects/schoolsparrow/app/jobs/listing_image_job.rb:31:in `perform'
    /Users/tomb/Projects/schoolsparrow/lib/tasks/update.rake:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `block in execute'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:271:in `execute'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:213:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:193:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/task.rb:182:in `invoke'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/rake:22:in `load'
    /Users/tomb/.rbenv/versions/2.3.7/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => update:listing_images
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re passing an array of `Rets::Parser::Multipart::Part` objects to `ActiveStorage::Attached::Many#attach`. It doesn’t know how to handle them.

For each photo, call `#attach` with an IO and a filename:

```
photos.each_with_index do |photo, index|
  listing.images.attach(io: StringIO.new(photo.body), filename: "photo-#{index + 1}.png")
end
```

Comment: That works!  But I had to add this to development.rb due to squlite3 busy exception errors:  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :inline.  Also, the (1) after each_with_index caused an error and I removed.  Possibly a typo?  Thank you!

Comment: I tweaked the code example. I thought `each_with_index` accepted a starting index, but I misremembered.